# How can we work with field extensions when our base fields aren't actually subfields?

Tags: field-theory, foundations

I've been wondering this for a little while. Say we are working with the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, and then we wish to talk about the extension fields $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, by which we mean the fields $E$, such that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq E$. We first give the example of $\mathbb{R}$ as an extension field, which I suppose is agreeable, given that we do not usually go into the formal constructions of the real numbers.

But then, for example, how to we justify saying then that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$? If we have our initial construction of $\mathbb{R}$, and then decide to work with pairs in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ defined in the usual way such that $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd,bc+ad)$ and call that $\mathbb{C}$ then the fact is that $\mathbb{R}$ is $\textbf{not}$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. The only solution I can see to this is that in reality a field extension $E$ is just a field for which there exists a subfield $F'$ which is isomorphic to our base field $F$...or else redefine "subfield".

At first I found the subobject classifier as introduced in Lawvere's "Sets for mathematics" so be unwieldy....but now I see that it in fact is a reflection of the fact that our "subsets" rarely actually appear to be subsets...

My question isn't the best phrased, I think, but that's more due to a general confusion about this.

Comment: There is no reason to want a specific incarnation of $\mathbb{R}$ as being "the real numbers". Any field isomorphic to it will be just as good.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So then are we using some kind of principle that propositions are only proven up to isomorphism?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. When we say that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ we have a specific subset in mind usually.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, yes, but we are picking somewhat arbitrarily, seeing how so far as I can see any isomorphic subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ would do.

Comment: That depends on what the statement actually is. Sure, it seems somewhat arbitrary how we pick the subfield (though I am not sure I can see an easy way to pick another one).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As a wild guess, the open interval $(-1,1)$?  A solution I'm seeing is that maybe in fact these objects are all the same, and are only defined by what we do to them...

Comment: That open interval is not a subfield.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Like I said, a very rough guess, I think that would only be an isomorphic set

Comment: What do you mean isomorphic? As a set? Sure, but that is not very interesting.

Comment: Isomorphisms of this kind are used all the time - e.g. when constructing "the" rationals from the integers. The points in the Euclidean Plane can be identifies with the complex numbers - we call it "the" complex plane - but is it "just" an isomorphic copy? In what circumstances do you see these distinctions making a difference?

Comment: BTW, for any field of characteristic $0$ there is a unique subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. So for extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ there is really no problem.

Comment: @MarkBennet Was that for me? Assuming so, my thinking at the moment is that it won't, so long as we get our isomorphisms right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have objects $A,B$ with a *canonical* embedding $i\colon A\to B$, you can always view $A$ as a subobject of $B$ and, if those objects have something like "underlying sets", also $A\subseteq B$. As a last resort you may replace $B$ with someting like $(B\setminus i(A))\cup A$. (Actually, even more surgery has to be done if $A\cap B$ happens to be nonempty in an "unexpected" way). This allows us to consider $A$ as subset of (something just as good as) $B$ after all, thus allowing us to write
$$\mathbb N \subset \mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R\subset \mathbb C$$
even though we *construct* these sets as

- pairs ($\mathbb C$ from $\mathbb R$)
- equivalence classes of pairs ($\mathbb Z$ from $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Q$ from $\mathbb Z$)
- equivalence classes of sequences ($\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$)

Strictly speaking, $2\in \mathbb N$ is therefore not the same as $+2\in\mathbb Z$, or $\frac21\in\mathbb Q$ or $2.000\ldots\in\mathbb R$ or $2+0i\in\mathbb C$.
The main point is however that once we have performed one construction or the other (e.g., for $\mathbb R$: Cauchy sequences modulo zero sequences *or* Dedekind cuts) we can forget the construction used and identify all those incarnations of the ultimately same number.

Comment: So we just identify the isomorphic copy and say that is that?

Comment: @Nethesis Yes, but note that there is only *one* isomorphic copy that is a substructure in these inclusions (except $\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z$). It may get clumsier when we say something like $S^1\subset \Bbb R^2$. I wonder what a category theorist would say about this apparent distinction.

Comment: @GPerez Doesn't this just ruin the fact that we say $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ implies $A=B$?

Comment: @Nethesis How so?

Comment: @GPerez Because if we are simply turning inclusion into a combination of an injection and an actual inclusion, then nothing works. We can't even say that $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ with this, because we have no information on whether either of the mappings is invertible.

Comment: @GPerez This is snowballing in my head now. If we turn subset into subobject, then a bunch of things simply don't work. We can't just identify one $\mathbb{Q}$ and call it the proper rational numbers, because then it's practically not a subset of anything.

Comment: @GPerez At the moment a lot seems to be just nonsense, now.

Comment: @Nethesis Indeed there are (infinitely) many sets that deserve to be called "rational numbers". I don't really know how to convince you that there's no nonsense involved, because I can't identify exactly which part you think is problematic. I do assure you though, everything works out. If you wish, once we have assured (by explicit construction) the existence of a set endowed with $\Bbb C$'s axioms, we can do everything else in subsets of this set, and all inclusions will be "real" inclusions.

Comment: @GPerez Okay, I'll try to be clearer. 
Here's is my problem. We have infinitely many possible constructions of sets isomorphic to the rational numbers. We can take subsets of real numbers, complex numbers, quaternions, even matrices to get the rationals. The issue is that it's only guided by isomorphism and labelling convention. If we say $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq E$ to mean "there exists a subset of $E$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, then under this kind of definition we could also have $E\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and yet have neither equality nor isomorphism come out of it.

Comment: @GPerez The issue is not really with $\mathbb{Q}$, though. It's that then how on earth does this work with the general notion of a base field? We can't have a preferred isomorphism, there, so we need to work with actual inclusion. But then $\mathbb{Q}$ just becomes a completely different case, rather than a prime example.

Comment: @Nethesis Note that I spoke of *canonical* embeddings. If you have canonical embeddings $\mathbb Q\to E$ and $E\to\mathbb Q$, then they wouldcombine into a canonical embedding $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ that is not the identity

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Just so I'm understanding you, what exactly do you mean by "canonical"?

Comment: @Nethesis A chain of morphisms $$A\hookrightarrow \hspace{-8pt} \rightarrow B\hookrightarrow E\hookrightarrow \hspace{-8pt} \rightarrow C\hookrightarrow A $$
*does* in fact establish an isomorphism between $A$ and $E$. We could dispell "$\subset$" altogether and only work with "$\hookrightarrow$" and argue with such chains if we wanted to. Equality of sets is a special case of isomorphism, which is all we care about anyways (isomorphism, that is).

Comment: @GPerez So in fact $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ does in fact imply that $A$ is isomorphic to $B$? Even if the monomorphisms that view the two aren't inverses of each other?

Comment: @Nethesis Yes. In the above example the invertible arrows aren't those from $B$ to $E$ and from $C$ to $A$. The isomorphism is given by the composition $A\hookrightarrow \hspace{-8pt} \rightarrow B\hookrightarrow E$, with inverse the composition $E\hookrightarrow \hspace{-8pt} \rightarrow C\hookrightarrow A$. You should check this for yourself though.

Comment: @GPerez Oh wait, sorry of course that chain gives an isomorphism. What I mean is that if you have two arbitrary monomorphisms between $A$ and $B$, how does that show they are isomorphic?

Comment: @GPerez Okay the emphases on the arrows was missed. So bold is isomorphism and not bold is just monomorphism. But then what is $C$ just mapped (thinking with mappings, for a second) entirely onto one element of $A$? It would prove nothing.

Comment: @GPerez I should clarify my comments above my previous one. My "$B$" was your "$E$".

Comment: @GPerez What is $B$ and $C$ in your example?

Answer (score 1):

"Subfield" is a structure, not a property. That is, when you want to exhibit a field $K$ as a subfield of a field $L$, you need to specify some data, namely the data of a homomorphism $K \to L$. The way in which $K$ sits as a subfield of $L$ can vary a great deal depending on the choice of this homomorphism: for example, it turns out that $\mathbb{C}$ has a proper subfield isomorphic to itself.

When we say that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, we mean that we've picked a particular homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, namely $a \mapsto a + 0i$, and that we want to think of real numbers as particular complex numbers via this homomorphism.

For the same reason, "field extension" is a structure, not a property.

Comment: So is that the reason I've come to this revelation that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ is meaningless?

Comment: There's more, I didn't mean to post that so soon, just wait

Comment: @Nethesis: it's not meaningless, it just has to be interpreted carefully. It should not be interpreted as "there exists an injection from $A$ into $B$"; rather, it should be interpreted as "I have in mind a particular injection from $A$ into $B$." (This is if $A$ and $B$ are just two sets, hanging out; if $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of a third set $C$, then it's perfectly meaningful to say that $A \subseteq B$ as subsets.)

Comment: Because if $A\subseteq B$ under $f:A\to B$, denoted $A \subseteq_f B$, but $B\subseteq_g A$, where $g$ is anything but $f^{-1}$, then it really does prove nothing. However, if $g=f^{-1}$ then we get isomorphism. And presumably a further restriction gives the actual equality of sets.

Comment: @Nethesis: I should mention that it also depends to some extent on what your underlying set theory looks like. In ZFC, the statement $A \subseteq B$ makes sense for two sets $A$ and $B$, just hanging out: it means that every element of $A$ is an element of $B$. But this is a terrible way to interpret $\subseteq$, and in particular depending on how you construct the real and complex numbers, it may or may not be true that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ in this sense... I prefer not to allow $\subseteq$ to have this meaning.

Comment: And I don't really like it either. The issue is is how can we interpret the subobject meaning from category theory, which you appear to prefer, and still prefer the intuitive meaning? Is it only possible to at best get isomorphism? Is that enough?

Comment: It's just that basic equality proofs seem to rely on $A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq A \Rightarrow A=B$.

Comment: @Nethesis: I don't really know what you mean by "basic equality proofs." Again, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a set $S$, this has a straightforward and uncontroversial meaning: $A \subseteq B$ means that if $s \in A$ then $s \in B$. Similarly, $B \subseteq A$ means that if $s \in B$, then $s \in A$. Hence if both are true, then $A$ and $B$ have the same members, so $A = B$ (as subsets of $S$). This continues to be true in ZFC with the weird meaning of $\subseteq$.

Comment: I swear you just said that that is the weird meaning of subset? That's certainly the one used in ZFC. Under that meaning $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\textbf{not}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Under the meaning involving monomorphisms it is. The issue is that if you use the monomorphism one then you don't get equality out of mutual subsets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24884/discussion-between-nethesis-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: @Nethesis: okay, forget ZFC. Here is a general definition in an arbitrary category: if $S$ is an object, then the *category of subobjects* of $S$ is the category whose objects are pairs $(X, m)$ of an object $X$ and a monomorphism $m : X \to S$ (and whose morphisms are commuting triangles). It's an exercise to show that this category is a preorder: that is, between any two objects there is at most one morphism. Hence if $X, Y$ (suppressing the monomorphisms) are two subobjects, then you can define $X \subseteq Y$ to mean that there is a morphism from $X$ to $Y$, or equivalently...

Comment: ...that $m_X : X \to S$ factors through $m_Y : Y \to S$. If this happens it happens uniquely so it is really a property and not a structure. Then it is straightforwardly true that if $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$ then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic *as subobjects* (that is, in the category of subobjects). This definition generally reproduces the usual notion of subobject in most concrete categories, although occasionally it can behave strangely.

Comment: Okay, so in the sense of there simply existing monomorphism between $A$ and $B$ it doesn't mean much. If there is a third object $S$ which they both monomorph into, then there is only one morphism and one inverse which will give a commuting triangle?

Comment: @Nethesis: yes, but the monomorphisms are part of the data of being a subobject; that's still a structure. What I'm saying is that if $A$ and $B$ are already regarded as subobjects of a third object, then containment becomes a property of $A$ and $B$ *as subobjects*.

Comment: Then what does that show for $A$ and $B$? Sure they are isomorphic as subjects but what does that mean elsewhere? I'm starting to fail to see where this is relevant to the twin issues of $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq A\Rightarrow A=B$.

Comment: Here's what I got from what you said. The monomorphism notion of $A\subseteq B$ only characterises "there exists a monomorphism between $A$ and $B$" and nothing more. However if you have a third object $S$ to which both $A$ and $B$ are subobjects, then you may have $A$ and $B$ being isomorphic as subobjects if there exists a monomorphism and an inverse which filters through the morphisms to $S$. The issue I'm confused by is what is the relevance of this to the usual notion? What does being isomorphic as subobjects then show?

Comment: @Nethesis: in a concrete category where the monomorphisms are the injective morphisms, being isomorphic as subobjects means being the same subobject in the usual sense. For example, in sets it means being the same subset, in groups it means being the same subgroup, etc.